# How to get unique php-extension instance for each php thread?

Tags: php, pthreads, php-extension

My friends, I have a difficult task, creating php extension (I will call it custom-extension) with libssh2. Extension must work with php extension pthreads together. Let's say I have 100 php threads. As I see all threads has the same custom-extension instance. And, as I think, this is why I get a lot problems when I use more then 1 thread. For example global variables in custom-extension C code will be owerwritten by pthreads. Sure, I may use `__thread`, but it doesn't solve the problem. Libssh2 usage in custom-extension makes things more difficult. I will not provide any code, because I think it doesn't matter.

So the question is: is it possible to make each php pthread use own new custom-extension instance ? I think it will be better for my case, because then I will encapsulate custom-extension for each thread. Also libssh2, used in custom-extension also should be new instance for each thread. This way has to save me for variables overwritting and other segfaults errors.

- I have compiled custom-extension with `--enable-pthreads=shared`
- My environment is Ubuntu 18.04 64bit, PHP-CLI 7.2.2 ZTS